# How to customize and add details like version in robot framework report.html file?

Tags: html, report, robotframework

I want to add details like version of the application on which the test are run in my report.html file.Is it possible?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

[Set suite metadata](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Suite%20Metadata) allows you to associate key/value pairs with a suite.

The following test illustrates how it works:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Example
    Set suite metadata  program under test  my cool program
```

When the test runs, this is what appears in report.html:

[image: screenshot of report.html]

This information will appear in the log like so:

[image: screenshot of log.html]

Comment: I think it is worth to mention that the top suite metadata could be set from command line as well. http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#setting-free-metadata